# Почему выдаёт ошибку с IDENTITY колонкой: ERROR 1064 (42000)?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

```
CREATE TABLE Investors
(
    IDInvestor INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    InvestorName VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PasportSN CHAR (11) NOT NULL,
    PhoneNumber CHAR (15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (PasportSN),
    UNIQUE (PhoneNumber)
)
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTITY,
> InvestorName VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
> PasportSN CHAR (11) NOT NULL,
> Phon' at line 3

Comment: замените `IDENTITY` -> `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: mysql> CREATE TABLE Investors
    -> (
    -> IDInvestor INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> InvestorName VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    -> PasportSN CHAR (11) NOT NULL,
    -> PhoneNumber CHAR (15) NOT NULL,
    -> PRIMARY KEY (PasportSN),
    -> UNIQUE (PhoneNumber)
    -> )
    -> ;
ERROR 1075 (42000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
пробовал но другая ошибка

Comment: так написано же все в ошибке, автоинкрементируемое поле должно быть первичным ключом

Comment: @Dmitry, не обязательно первичным - достаточно уникальным

Comment: как сделать его уникальным ?

Comment: убрать второй первичный ключ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых замените `IDENTITY` -> `AUTO_INCREMENT`, во-вторых сделайте столбец `IDInvestor` уникальным (`UNIQUE`) или первичным (`PRIMARY KEY`) ключем:

```
CREATE TABLE Investors
(
    IDInvestor INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    InvestorName VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PasportSN CHAR (11) NOT NULL,
    PhoneNumber CHAR (15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (PasportSN),
    UNIQUE (PhoneNumber),
    UNIQUE (IDInvestor) 
);
```

[Тест](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a6R55U83C93EoDhYrAEZB1/0)

Comment: как сделать его уникальным ?

Comment: @ТигранБрагалян, я привел рабочий пример в ответе - `UNIQUE (IDInvestor)`

Comment: Спасибо, заработало

Comment: я дальше начал создавать таблицы и у меня похожая проблема 
CREATE TABLE Investments
(
 IDInvestment INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 AccountNumber INT NOT NULL,
 Type VARCHAR (7) NOT NULL,
 InvSum INT,
 Per_Cents FLOAT NOT NULL,
 Currency VARCHAR (6) NOT NULL, 
 OpenningDate DATETIME,
 PasportSN CHAR (11) NOT NULL,
            UNIQUE (AccountNumber),
 FOREIGN KEY (PasportSN) REFERENCES Investors(PasportSN)
)
Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: @ТигранБрагалян, если у вас возник новый вопрос - откройте новый вопрос на SO